# How can I select with regex commas outside of brackets?

Tags: php, regex

I have the below text and I want to replace with regex only the commas from what this regex will select `/\).+?(\(|$)/i`, it's a regex within regex I suppose.

I am using PHP

`Fresh Basil (50%),Dextrose ,Canola Oil ,Humectant (Glycerol) ,Whey (Milk) ,Acidity Regulators (Sodium Lactate, Citric Acid) ,Salt ,Antioxidants (Sodium Ascorbate, Ascorbic Acid, Citric Acid) ,Thickener (Xanthan Gum) ,Contains about 2 bunches of chopped fresh basil`

I guess I'm trying to replace only the commas outside of the brackets and keep the ones inside, if that makes any sense.

Comment: XY problem?  Seems like you want to separate the items delimited by comma except within parenthesis.  Maybe join it with a different delimiter?

Comment: Where does this string originate? Do you have the ability to modify its format at its source?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/bT5wY8 ?

Comment: @Michael - No, unfortunately there is nothing I can do to modify the source code!

Comment: @Enissay - your regex worked like a charm, I had to remove some empty values but brilliant and short! thanks! Can you post as answer, and I will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
/\(.*?\)\K|(,)/g
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fE1iN7)</kbd>

```
NODE                        EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\(                          '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                     Any character except \n (0 or more times
                            (matching the least amount possible) => Ungreedy)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\)                          ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\K                          Resets the starting point of the reported match.
                            Any previously consumed characters are no longer 
                            included in the final match
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                           OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(                           group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                       ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)                           End of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I decided not to use regex for this!

Here is my solution in case someone is wondering...

```
<?php

$ingredientsptag = 'Fresh Basil (50%),Dextrose ,Canola Oil ,Humectant (Glycerol) ,Whey (Milk) ,Acidity Regulators (Sodium Lactate, Citric Acid) ,Salt ,Antioxidants (Sodium Ascorbate, Ascorbic Acid, Citric Acid) ,Thickener (Xanthan Gum) ,Contains about 2 bunches of chopped fresh basil';

$counter = 0;
$ingredientsString = '';
for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen($ingredientsptag); $i++ )  { 
    $character = substr( $ingredientsptag, $i, 1 );

    if ( $character == '(' ) {
        $counter++;
    }

    if ( $character == ')' ) {
        $counter--;
    }

    if ( $character == ',' && $counter == 0 ) {
        $ingredientsString .= '||';
    } else {
        $ingredientsString .= $character;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Even though this solution works, I used in the end @Enissay's solution as it's more elegant and performs much faster than mine!